# NSFileManager's currentDirectoryPath returns root directory when .app is run at Desktop

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, executable

I'm developing a basic web service, and am working on the login screen. When the user presses the "login" button, I want it to activate a `NSTask` that runs a binary which is **bundled** with the application (which performs the login with the given credentials). Right now, I get the working directory, and append the relative location of the binary to the working directory to run it. The binary runs fine when I just place the binary in a static location on my computer, but I would prefer to bundle the binary *in the app's resources* instead (unless this is a bad idea).

The gist of my code is available [here](https://gist.github.com/stevenschmatz/7efb18ea3444e37d1645).

**Where is the best place to put a binary in the XCode project directory, so that I can bundle it in the folder "X.app/Contents"?**

Currently, I am just getting the current working directory, and then appending the relative location of the binaries to this string. The following code is contained in an override of the `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil` method:

```
NSFileManager *filemgr = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];    
self.pathString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:filemgr.currentDirectoryPath];
```

I launch the task with the following code (wrapped in a method in a subclassed `NSViewController`):

```
NSString *launchPath = [self.pathString stringByAppendingString:@"/X.app/Contents/Resources/loginFromClient"];

NSTask *task;
task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: launchPath];

NSArray *arguments;
arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:username, nil];
[task setArguments: arguments];

NSPipe *pipe;
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput: pipe];

NSFileHandle *file;
file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

[task launch];

NSData *data;
data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

NSString *string;
string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This works when the application is run in the Debug folder. 
HOWEVER, when I try to move it to a different location (ie, copying the X.app to Desktop), the `filemgr` reports that the `currentDirectoryPath` is the root directory ("/").

This brings me to two questions:

1. **Why is the NSFileManager reporting that the current directory is "/", when it should be "/Users/stevenschmatz/Desktop/X.app"?**
2. **Is there any way just to refer to a subdirectory in the .app folder directly, so you can run a binary regardless of the app's location without finding the working directory at all?**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: As Gerd notes, there's no "**should**" about the working directory. Your expectations in that regard are simply unfounded. The working directory is really only relevant for command-line programs and is for the use of the user, to allow them to provide relative paths after they've `cd`-ed to a directory of their choice.

Comment: Also check out the NSString methods
`+ (instancetype)stringWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error` or  `- (instancetype)initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error` to save yourself a whole lot of code.

Comment: Thank you both very much, I will check this out :)

Answer (score 1):

The `currentDirectoryPath` is dependent on the launch environment and has nothing to do with the location of your application.

To get data inside your app bundle, look at `[NSBundle mainBundle]`. An equivalent to your code above would be:

```
NSString *launchPath=[NSBundle.mainBundle
    pathForResource:@"loginFromClient"
    ofType:nil
];
```